# Cannot get bash to match whitespaces in a regular expression that is delimited by [[ ]] in an if satement

Tags: regex, bash, if-statement, whitespace, fastq

I am developing what should be a simple script to read a file line by line, assess the contents of each line, and process the line data depending on it line number. For some reason, I cannot get a regex that matches white spaces. [:space:], [[:space:]], [:blank:], \s, \ , , and " " have all failed.

My data is formatted as follows (fastq format):

```
    @SRR573708.2 2 length=100
    AAAACGTTAATATTTATTGAAATTGTT
    +SRR573708.2 2 length=100
    HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
```

I would like to reformat it to:

```
    @SRR573708.2/2
    AAAACGTTAATATTTATTGAAATTGTT
    +SRR573708.2/2
    HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
```

It is important, however, that I check each line to make sure it is formatted correctly before printing it to a new file. My last attempt at generating a reformatted file produced some really bizzare results at the end of the file. My code is:

```
    i=1
    while read LINE; do
        if (( $i > 4 )); then break; fi
        if (( $i % 4 == 1 )); then
            if [[ $data =~ ^@SRR[0-9]{6}[[:blank:]] ]]; then
                awk -v IFS=" " -v OFS="" -v ORS="" -v SUFFIX=$SUFFIX -v OUTPUT_FILE=$OUTPUT_FILE ' {print $1,SUFFIX,"\n"    } ' <<< $data
                i=$(( $i + 1 ))
            else
                echo -e "error at line ${i}"; echo "${data}"; exit 1; fi
        elif (( $i % 4 == 2 )); then echo -e "$LINE" 
            i=$(( $i + 1 ))

        elif (( $i % 4 == 3 )); then
            echo $data
            awk -v IFS=" " -v OFS="" -v ORS="" -v SUFFIX=$SUFFIX -v OUTPUT_FILE=$OUTPUT_FILE ' {print $1,SUFFIX,"\n"  } ' <<< $data
            i=$(( $i + 1 ))

elif (( $i % 4 == 0 )); then echo -e "$LINE" 
    i=$(( $i + 1 ))

else
    echo -e "number of liness is not divisible by 4. Program Terminated.\nProblem encountered at line ${i}."
    exit 1
fi

done < $INPUT_FILE
```

I get the error message:

```
    error at line 1
    @SRR573708.2 2 length=100
```

Any suggestions as to how to match a whitespace in a regex if-statement, preferable matching only space and tab characters and not newline characters.

Comment: Did you really mean _exactly one `[[:blank:]]` character_? Perhaps you want a `*` after it? Or is the problem that you don't match the `.`?

Comment: The reason your regex match is failing is that, after `SRR[0-9]{6}` you have ".2" and not whitespace.

Comment: You `read LINE` and then examine `$data`. Is that a copy-and-paste error or is it for real?

Comment: please realize that `awk` is a program designed specifically to "read a file line by line, assess the contents of each line, and process the line data " (on many criteria, including line number). You could convert this into 1 awk process very easily. Good luck.

Comment: Note: This monstrosity `awk -v IFS=" " -v OFS="" -v ORS="" -v SUFFIX=$SUFFIX -v OUTPUT_FILE=$OUTPUT_FILE ' {print $1,SUFFIX,"\n"    } ' <<< $data` could be written rather more simply as `echo "${data%% *}$SUFFIX"`, or if you prefer, `echo "${data/ */$SUFFIX}"`. (I'm not sure what you're using OUTPUT_FILE for.)

Comment: And looking at your required output, you're only removing `length=100`? How about `sed s/length=[0-9][0-9]*$//' file > outFile` ? Good luck.

Comment: Thank you all for your advice. I had indeed missed a "." character in my pattern match. Also, the code ran much more efficiently once I rearranged it to run entirely through awk

Answer (score 0):

A working awk code is below (although it is not as elegant and streamlined as rici's code):

```
    awk -v i=1 -v IFS=" " -v OFS="" -v ORS="" -v SUFFIX=$SUFFIX -v OUTPUT_FILE=$OUTPUT_FILE -v nchars=0 -v DIRECTION=$DIRECTION ' {
        if (i%4==1 && $0~/^@SRR[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.[0-9]+\.$DIRECTION[[:blank:]][0-9]+[[:blank:]]length=100$/)
            { printf "%s%s\n",$1,SUFFIX >> OUTPUT_FILE; i++ }
        else if (i%4==2 && $0~/^[AGCTNagctn\-]+$/)
            { nchars=length($0);printf "%s\n",$1 >> OUTPUT_FILE;i++ }
        else if (i%4==3 && $0~/^\+SRR[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.[0-9]+[[:blank:]][0-9]+[[:blank:]]length=100$/)
            { printf "%s%s\n",$1,SUFFIX >> OUTPUT_FILE; i++}
        else if (i%4==0 && $0~/.*/ && nchars==length($0))
            { printf "%s\n",$1 >> OUTPUT_FILE;i++}
        else
            {printf "error at line %s:\n%s\n\n",i,$0; exit 1}
        }' $INPUT_FILE
```